# Is there are way to split videos into smaller chunks of videos in python

Tags: python, opencv, video, split

I'm developing a system that will make use of multiple videos and I'm planning for the user to input 1 hour long videos but before analyzing the video, I'm planning to put an algorithm using python or opencv (which one's possible) and divide it into segments of 5-minute videos.

Any answers will help, thank you!

Comment: you can use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) to split it, or modules based on `ffmpeg` like [python-ffmpeg](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) or [moviepy](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy). Or even use `subprocess` to run `ffmpeg` directly in Python.

Comment: Unix&Linux: [How can I use ffmpeg to split MPEG video into 10 minute chunks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1670/how-can-i-use-ffmpeg-to-split-mpeg-video-into-10-minute-chunks)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) to split it.

You can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to run `ffmpeg` directly in Python.
Or you can try to use modules based on ffmpeg like [python-ffmpeg](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) or [moviepy](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy).

---

I found examples in similar portal for `Unix&Linux`:
[How can I use ffmpeg to split MPEG video into 10 minute chunks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1670/how-can-i-use-ffmpeg-to-split-mpeg-video-into-10-minute-chunks)

One of them

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:05:00 -c copy output1.mp4
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:05:00 -to 00:10:00 -c copy output2.mp4
# ect.
```

so you can run it in `for`-loop

```
import subprocess

for number, start in enumerate(range(0, 60, 5), 1):
    end = start + 5

    cmd = [
          "ffmpeg", 
          "-i", "input.mp4", 
          "-ss", f"00:{start:02}:00",
          "-to", f"00:{end:02}:00",
          "-c", "copy",
          f"output{number:02}.mp4"
    ]

    print(" ".join(cmd))

    subprocess.run(cmd)
```

(`subprocess` needs list `cmd` when `shell=False`)

---

Or using other example - without `for`-loop

```
import subprocess

cmd = [    
    "ffmpeg",
    "-i", "input.mp4",
    "-c", "copy",
    "-map", "0",
    "-segment_time", "00:05:00",
    "-f", "segment",
    "-reset_timestamps", "1",
    "output-2-%02d.mp4"
]

print(" ".join(cmd))

subprocess.run(cmd)
```